# Google Sheets formula to wildcard lookup multiple values

Tags: google-sheets, match, vlookup

I'm given a list of strings in column A.

I'm also given a hierarchy in Column C.  The hierarchy contains a list of strings separated by a | delimiter.

I need to create a formula in Column D that will look through the hierarchy column and return the match from the list.  Note: The list will change.

The only way I can get this to work is using a chained IF ERROR with VLOOKUP, which does not look good and is hard to maintain.  I'm seeking a better solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

take:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A))))
```

but this is better:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C, "|", " "), 
 "\b("&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, A2:A)&")\b")))
```

keep in mind its case sensitive unless you use `(?i)` flag